# Trying to append a list of values to existing json file as a new column

Tags: python, json, append

I have a function that has returned a list of values. I would like to make this list as the last column in my dataset that is a json file. Currently I have a url of the dataset from github. How can I append the values as the last column (one value per row), using the function that has given me the list of values?

Currently my json file is saved as:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

url = 'githublink'
df = pd.read_json(url)
```

and my function is in the format:

```
def func():
    newlist = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        newlist.append(i)
    return newlist 

output = func() #saved output of the function
```

Comment: Please include minimal-reproducible-example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

obj = json.loads('json_as_str', object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
last_item = obj.popitem()

your_lov = yourLovFunction()
obj[last_item[0]] = last_item[1] + your_lov

json.dumps(obj)
```

You get an OrderedDict, so the keys are ordered if you convert your JSON-String to an Python-Object. You pop out the last item of this dict and get a Tuple, where the first element is the key and the second one the value.

So you assign again the same key and do the + operator on both lists.

So if you have an object like

```
{ "a": 123, "b" : [2,3,4]}
```

and get out the "b" and combine your lov with [2,3,4] and assign "b" again, this should do it.

Comment: Am I replacing 'json_as_str' with "df" from my code? I am struggling to understand how I incorporate the part where I have read the url to my github data into this method...

Comment: You should get the content fo your JSON in this example with requests

`import requests
r = requests.get('your_url')
json_str = str(r.content)`

This would be the easiest, in my opinion.